# Make a minGW console program run without the console

Tags: c, console, mingw

I made a console program in MinGW which performs network and file actions. However, its a console program. How do I make it run silently, no consoles, no windows?

Comment: You mean as a windows service? Or as a process owned by the current user that's invisible? For the latter, make it a windows subsystem app not a console app and just don't open any windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindowHandle(),SW_HIDE);`

- [`GetConsoleWindowHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the window handle to the console.
- [`ShowWindow(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to alter the visibilty.