# C console application without console or run at background with hidden

Tags: c, console

I want to run C console application without window or at background with hidden. Please guide me to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for some `CreateProcess(...)` samples? It's hard to imagine this is about any OS other than Windows(R).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a minGW console program run without the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553110/make-a-mingw-console-program-run-without-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows use `ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false)` to hide the console window. It will still be running in the background and is not visible on the taskbar.

However you will have to run a task manager like `Taskmgr.exe` to find it and shut it down.

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <iostream>     
using namespace std;


int main () {   

    ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);

    while(true) {
                 // Do your hidden stuff in here
    }   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a c++ code, but commenting c++ codes, it works for C. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Can use C in with "stdbool.h" like
ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);

or

ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), 0);